# Azure Device Update for IoT Hub

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-update

I have microcontroller ASUS Tinker Board 2, with Debian 10 on it. I want to implement Device Update, installed `deviceupdate-agent` on device. Made configuration and can listen for updates. The question is how to create import manifest for updating device image or device version. Should I load image file or it will download automatically.

Comment: IoT Hub update [manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub-device-update/update-manifest)

Answer (score 0):

Reference taken from [Update to be imported into Azure Device Update for IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub-device-update/create-update)

- Azure CLI extensions to be installed before use. The azure-iot extension is used in the article’s commands. Use the command `az extension update --name azure-iot`to ensure sure you’re using the most recent version of the extension.
- Update import manifest :

```
az iot du update init v5 \
    --update-provider <replace with your Provider> \
    --update-name <replace with your update Name> \
    --update-version <replace with your update Version> \
    --compat <replace with the property name>=<replace with the value your device will report> <replace with the property name>=<replace with the value your device will report> \
    --step handler=<replace with your chosen handler> properties=<replace with any handler properties (JSON-formatted)> \
    --file path=<replace with path(s) to your update file(s), including the full file name>
```

- For more details Refer this [Device Update for IoT Hub update manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub-device-update/update-manifest)